# Adding header to a Jtable after initializing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

As far as tutorials that i have seen, everyone seem to initialize the JFrame with ( object [][] , object[] ) , so they can use the second argument as a header. i have initialized my table with ( int , int ) so my table's header right now just says [A and B.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNGKk.png) Is there an easy way to change the header cells later?

Comment: It's not clear if you are referring to javax.swing.JFrame constructor or what else? Please add a section of code to make it clearer. What is your link related to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the `DefaultTableModel` API.

There are many constructor you can use to initialize the table how you want.

The basic logic should be something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```

> you can't update the header after the initialization of the table?

Yes, you can. I just gave you the easiest way.

If you want to make more work for yourself then you can:

1. get the `TableColumnModel` of the table.
2. iterate through the `TableColumn` of the `TableColumnModel`.
3. update the header value of each `TableColumn`.

> everyone seem to initialize the JFrame with ( object [][] , object[] )

And that is not a good way to create the table, since you need to have a fixed size table and you will know need to see each cell manually.

Instead you use Vectors and dynamically add the data so the table can contain any number of row. Don't limit the size of the table. Learn how to design for dynamic data which will give you flexibility and also supports static data as well.

You could for example just set the column names of the table model with 0 rows of data. Then you simply use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add data.

Comment: Is that a no, you can't update the header after the initialization of the table? Because everything else is already done ( see screenshot in my post ). just want to update the header **after** initialization

Comment: i see, thanks!     first time using swing at all :-)